# Speed up google Cloud storage transfer to s3

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, rsync, gsutil

I have a need to daily export large chunks of data from google storage to s3(a few hundred GBs). Since, gsutil rsync seems the only way to do it, I want to pace up things a bit.

It's too slow syncing from gs to s3 as the docs itself say " Since cross-provider gsutil data transfers flow through the machine where gsutil is running....". 
So, it downloads and uploads the data from the machine triggering the rsync command.
If anyone has worked on something similar, let me know.

The 'rsync -m' doesn't help either.

Would a better machine improve the results?
Could we use multiple machines to run rsync in parallel to speed up?

Thanks!

Comment: You said "export large chunks" but then you've also talked about using rsync... which seems like a very inefficient way of syncing between two things that aren't filesystems.  What's the real nature of the transfer work and why are you transferring large chunks *daily*?  (Assuming you are aware that neither GC nor AWS network allows you to export data for free...)

Comment: What you are saying is absolutely right. Just that there is an entity E1 in GS from where we have to draw the data(there are many such source entities, not just GS).
The processing side entity P1....Pn are EMRs sitting on EC2 - everything AWS so the common point has been the data in s3 for processing side.
Writing a spark job might help but it ll essentially have to do the similar thing of moving data across clouds

Answer (score 4):

If you run the gsutil rsync command from Compute Engine (rather than from a machine on your premises), that will avoid using extra network bandwidth from Google to your premises and then from your premises to Amazon.

Comment: Or run it on EC2.

Comment: Hey Mike, yeah Compute Engine makes sense but right now we have all the other infra on EC2 so kind of, can't go that way. 
@Michael-sqlbot, we are running it on EC2 itself.
It improved on using a bigger ec2 instance - with more cores, RAM and I/0. I was looking for a better approach than scaling the machine hardware.

Comment: Also, I had two queries :
1. does increasing the disk size on which 'gsutil rsync' is running, improve the speed?
2. can we run gsutil rsync on a set of machines at one time to create some kind of parallelism?

Comment: Yes, you can run gsutil across multiple machines to increase parallelism; see https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#copying-tofrom-subdirectories-distributing-transfers-across-machines